# Windows boot suddenly broken --> Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS / Windows 10 multiboot with Grub

Tags: dual-boot

All has been fine for a month or so since I installed Win10 and Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS side by side (from scratch). Bios is running UEFI boot mode. Now suddenly when selecting Windows from grub, windows starts in startup repair wich seems to be infinite loop (repair is unsuccesfull according to windows. Selecting Ubuntu from grub menu starts it and it works fine.

Have tried updating grub, have tried running boot repair, no joy :(
Also if I change the boot order and try direct boot from windows bootmanger, same infinite repairloop occurs.

Here's the pastebin from boot-repair-tool ---->
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2SZ2VNWF39/

Any help appreciated

-k-

Comment: What brand/model system? grub only boots working Windows or Windows that is not hibernated, nor needs chkdsk. Can you directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu, not grub? And maybe f8 for Windows repair console? Windows may turn fast start back on with updates, so that may need turning off again. Not sure why efibootmgr is giving error on deleting & adding new UEFI entry. Does your UEFI have some sort of locking?

Comment: This system runs on Dell latitude E5450 laptop... No locks on at BIOS Also I shutdown windows normally and logged to Ubuntu, so no hibernation or other anomalies that would need checkdisk that I know. I wonder could it have any effect to windows boot that I have Windows installation partition (c:) mounted @ Ubuntu, and I have occasionally browsed that partition from Linux to find some files ?

Comment: Generally the Linux NTFS driver will not let you see the NTFS partition if hibernation is on or chkdsk is needed, unless you force it in read-only mode. But Windows does turn fast start up back on with updates, which you may not see in background. Have you tried f8 when directly booting Windows, or running Windows repair console in Windows 10 installer?

Comment: Yes I have tried to directly boot to windblows. Also have ran the repair console, result is "windows was unable to repair........"

Comment: Btw, if the windows fastboot feature is turned on by windblows updates, is there anyway to disable it without fully started windows ?? For example command line through F8 ?

Comment: This is an Ubuntu forum. We know just a little about Windows. Suggest Superuser or Windows forum for Windows issues.